# How do I use artifacts from 2 different pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center, azure-artifacts

I would like to use artifacts from 2 different pipelines in a 3rd pipeline.

Pipeline #1 builds a UITest.dll.
Pipeline #2 builds an APK file (or iOS app whatever). The sources for these pipelines use different repositories.

Pipeline #3 should use devops appcenter to install the app on an actual device in the cloud and run the UI tests. So pipeline #3 does not really use sources (which you must select when setting up a pipeline)

I do not want to run UI tests every time I build my app(s). and I do not need to run them every time I build the UITest (although I will consider this if necessary)

Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps for this approach you should use a Release Pipeline, instead a build pipeline. In Release pipeline you can use more than one artifact.

Comment: Hi @jpc, Is the answer below helpful for you? If you have any concern, please feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

For **Pipeline #1** and **#2** use build Pipeline, for **Pipeline #3** use relase pipeline.

As @Rogerson Nazário already mention it allows you to add multiple artifacts to your release pipeline definition like this:

[image]

After you add an artifacts to release you can use them both in any stage of this release.

> I do not want to run UI tests every time I build my app(s). and I do
> not need to run them every time I build the UITest (although I will
> consider this if necessary)

This can be solved by "Continuous deployment trigger". Green arrow points configured trigger for an artifact, blue arrow points disabled trigger. It means that if new version of an artifact will be available (e.g. from Pipeline #2) this release will run.

Additionally, if you use "[Publish test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)" task in the release pipeline correctly you will get a nice report and history for your tests runs:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I had not thought of release pipelines. I now have to figure how to run UI Tests... But this is a good start

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark my answer as accepted. Read this article about UI testing with Selenium: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops